# AngularDart build with Docker

Tags: angularjs, build, dart, docker

I try to deploy my angular-dart app with docker but can't get it to work.
Everything works on OS X but fails inside the container.

my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: myapp
dependencies:
  browser: any
  angular: 1.0.0
transformers:
  - angular
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM stackbrew/ubuntu:13.10
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https curl git
RUN sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
RUN sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list >     /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install dart/stable

env PATH $PATH:/usr/lib/dart/bin

ADD frontend/pubspec.yaml  /container/pubspec.yaml
ADD frontend/web          /container/web

WORKDIR /container
RUN pub build
```

Dart gets installed as expected (Dart VM version: 1.7.2)
But it fails at `pub build` with:

```
Error on line 6, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: Illegal argument(s): sdkDirectory must be provided.
- angular
  ^^^^^^^
```

I found this https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1270 which suggests to add the dartSDK path to pubspec.yaml. Which can't be the solution.

The app should be runnable on every machine.. not only on those where the dartSdk path matches with the hardcoded path in pubspec.yaml

Is there another way to fix this? or a workaround?

Comment: have you set the `DART_SDK` environment variable on your local system?

Comment: This is related to an issue in code_tranformers. See [issue 21225](http://dartbug.com/21225).

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Should be fixed in `code_transformers` 0.2.3+2 (see http://dartbug.com/21225)

#### Old

I don't know yet why this is necessary on some systems and not on others but this should fix it.

```dart
transformers:
- angular:
    sdkDirectory: "/usr/lib/dart"
```

See also https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1270#issuecomment-64967674 for an alternative approach using symlinks.

Comment: the sdkDirectory on my OSX machine differs from the sdkDirectory in the Docker container. So it will differ on a windows machine. The app should be deployable on any machine without changing the code

Comment: Yeah, I think this is an DI issue and should be filed there.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/cmbur7_B21Y/uhN5TiXUYwoJ